# javascript from onclick into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript code for a link click:

```
 document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = function {
        alert(this.href);
    };
```

and I want to separate the function part of it...I have

```
 document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = poro(this);
    function poro(yyyy) {
        alert(yyyy.href);
    };
```

But it is not working (says undefined in the alert)...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your not assigning the onclick event handler to a function, you are calling the function poro and passing `this` which at this point is *not* a hyperlink object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `this` as a parameter. `this` will be the context for the function when it is called. You should just have:

```
document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = poro;
function poro() {
    alert(this.href);
};
```

Comment: This works?!!?  how does javascript know that poro is a function if it does not have ()?

Comment: in JS, `()` executes the function. Functions can be passed around as variables by referencing it without its `()`.

Comment: function poro() { ... } is equivalent to var poro = function() { ... }, which is why this works.

Comment: @Dave this being Stack Overflow, that's wrong. They both allow you to pass `poro` around, but the former declares a named function while the latter assigns an anonymous function to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `(this)` and use `this` in the function instead of `yyyy`.

```
document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = poro;
function poro() {
    alert(this.href);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're immediately calling the `poro` function.
Essentially, you're telling Javascript that the element's `onclick` value will equal the result of calling the `poro(this [window] )` function.

To get around this, you can wrap the `poro(this)` function inside an empty function, like so:

```
document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = function(){poro(this)} function poro(yyyy) { alert(yyyy.href); };
```

You may also want to consider using an `eventListener`, as it allows room for expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! You should do:

```
document.getElementById('giddy').onclick = function(){ poro(this); }
function poro(yyyy) {
    alert(yyyy.href);
};
```

Note `poro(this);` wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: I always forget that they're called anonymous functions... not sure why.

Comment: Why would you create an anonymous function for this? This completely ignores one of the major benefits of JavaScript (functions can be passed as variables.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick` method.

Try this:

```
var giddy = document.getElementById('giddy');
giddy.addEventListener('click', function(e) { poro(this); }, false);
function poro(yyyy) {
  alert(yyyy.href);
}
```

Comment: why addeventlistener and not onclick?  is it better?

Comment: Please see this page for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

"Only one onclick handler can be assigned to an object at a time with this property. You may be inclined to use the addEventListener method instead, since it is more flexible and part of the DOM Events specification."

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jquery use :

```
$('#giddy').click(function(){ poro($(this));});
```

or you can use the [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function

```
$("#giddy").bind("click", $(this), poro);
```